# Bootstrap 4 and order after device type

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have this very simple snippet:

```
<div class="row">
  <div style="border:1px solid red" class="col-sm-8 order-sm-12">result</div>
  <div style="border:1px solid red" class="col-sm-4 order-sm-1">search</div>
</div>
```

I want to have **result** left and **search** right on all devices but mobile phone. When on a mobile phone i Want search in the top of the screen. I can see in bootstrap 4 pull left/right has been replaced by order. But in the above sample **result** is pulled right in desktop view?

How should order be understand? I would expect order-sm-1 would been on a screen of size small it would be the first (added to top) and order-sm-1 would mean add last? On other sizes the class would just be ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you just use `order-sm-*` it means "small and up". Therefore, you'd want to use...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div style="border:1px solid red" class="col-sm-8 order-1 order-sm-0">result</div>
        <div style="border:1px solid red" class="col-sm-4 order-0">search</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/fZoKZ56sXr

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I am not sure i completely understand how :D order-1 mean for all sizes it has order 1? And order-sm-0 means for small and upwards its order is 0? And the higher order, means it push upwards? so order1 is shown above order 0?